# Frobenius map, zeta functions of a variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, zeta-functions

I have difficulty understanding a passage about the zeta function of a variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Here $X$ is a closed set of an $n$-dimensional affine space over a field $k$ of characteristic $p$, $\phi$ is the Frobenius map that takes a point $(a_1,...,a_n)$ to $(a_1^p,...,a_n^p)$.

> if $x\in X$ is a point whose coordinates are in $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ and generate this field, then $X$ contains all the points $\phi^i(x)$ for $i=1,...,r$, and these are all distinct. We call a set $\xi=\{\phi^i(x)\}$ of this form a cycle, and the number $r$ of points of $\xi$ the degree of $\xi$. Now we can group together all the $\nu_r$ points $x\in X$ with coordinates in $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ into cycles. The coordinates of any of these points generate some subfield $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}\subset \mathbb{F}_{p^r}$, and it is known that
>   $d|r$. We get a formula $$\nu_r=\sum\limits_{d|r}d\mu_d$$ where $\mu_d$ is the number of cycles of degree $d$.

My questions
1, Why are $\phi^i(x)$ for $i=1,...,r$ all distinct?

2, Why are the cycles disjoint?

Comment: On Q.1: if $\phi^i(x)=\phi^j(x)$, then $\phi^{i-j}(x)=x$, and $\phi^{m(i-j)}(x)=x$ for all $m$. So $\phi^{i-j}$ generates a nontrivial subgroup of the Galois group fixing $x$, i.e. the coordinates of $x$ are in a smaller field than $\Bbb F_{p^r}$.

Comment: @Lubin Sorry I still don't get it :( I only understand why they are distinct when x has only one coordinate.

Comment: If $m_j$ is the smallest positive integer such the $x_j^{p^m_j}=x_j$ then the coordinates $x_j$, $j=1,2,\ldots,n$, generate the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^m}$ where $m=\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n)$. It follows that $m$ is also the smallest positive integer such that $\phi^m(x)=x$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks!